# Installing Teamviewer on Raspbian on Pi 3 B

Tags: raspberry-pi, teamviewer, raspbian

I'm trying to install Teamviewer on my raspberry Pi but no matter which package I choose it always says: `package architecture (whichever one I chose) does not match system (armhf)`
Which package should I be using?

Comment: I think there's no package for your hardware architecture. In that case the only solution is compiling from source but Teamviewer is closed source so... You need to find a different software.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia It probably took you more time to write that comment than it would have taken to go to the teamviewer website and see that there is a Pi version.  Just saying...

Comment: @Keltari lol...

Comment: OK, now I'm curious.  Last I knew, Teamviewer for Linux bundled a version of Wine and was still mostly a Windows application, just designed to run properly in Wine.  That obviously won't work on a Pi (unless they got _really_ crazy and also bundled a copy of QEMU's x86 userspace emulation), so they must have finally gotten around to writing some native Linux code.

Comment: I got it to work well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version is for the Raspberry Pi
 [https://pages.teamviewer.com/published/raspberrypi](https://pages.teamviewer.com/published/raspberrypi/)/

Also, here is a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/vr3Gf8vnKAg) video